# Why does Visual Studio 2013 Intellisense not recognize Bootstrap column size mixins?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less, intellisense, visual-studio-2013

I'm building a Bootstrap website and using LESS. It's all working fine, but Visual Studio's Intellisense doesn't recognize some of the mixins.

I use this following at the top of my LESS file:

```
@import "bootstrap/bootstrap.less";
```

Some mixins, like `.make-row()` are recognized, but the column ones, such as `.make-md-column(4)` aren't.

The LESS compiles fine, so it's no more than a minor annoyance, but, if any one knows how to fix it, please let me know.

I'm using the VS2013, Web Essentials and the latest versions of Bootstrap and the LESS source.

Comment: You make a typo maybe the mixins' names are separated by hyphens and not underscores;  `.make-md-column(@columns; @gutter: @grid-gutter-width) {`

Comment: Yes, sorry. That was a typo in the question - not the actual code. Have fixed the question now.

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily a fix more a workaround but you can add a reference path to your less file. This works in the same way as it would in a js file by giving you intellisense for that file.

**Example**

```
/// <reference path="variables.less" />

.bacon {
    color: @red; // Should have intellisense now.
}
```